# isolate vs. isolated

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I'm doing research paper and I want to write a sentence like

> We wanted to compare two groups **isolated**.

A colleague told me to write **isolate**, without **d**. I just checked, this is an actual adjective. (merriam-webster says: being alone, synonyms: solitary, isolated)

Do people still use this word?

Which word should I use in the above example?

When would I use **isolate** over **isolated** in general?

Comment: 'Isolated' is the past tense, and past participle of the verb 'to isolate'.  You need to refer to 'two isolated groups'.

Comment: We wanted to compare the two groups in isolation/separately

Comment: We want to compare two isolated groups. (In English generally adjectives precede the noun).

Answer (score 1):

"Isolate" is sometimes used (especially in science) to refer to the isolated group. So, in your example you might say:

> We wanted to compare two isolated groups. The first isolate we put in the blue room, the second isolate in the green room.

Here "isolate" refers individually to each of the groups.

> [See Wiktionary: isolate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/isolate)
>
> Noun isolate (plural isolates): Something that has been isolated.

Comment: Yes, but what about the adjective isolate?